# How to move on all input in form by Enter key in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that include some input.I want move on those by enter key. How can I do it by using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Stop form from going off on enter and then toggle form filed's on enter

```
$('form').keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
     }
});

$('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
         $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").bind("keydown", function(event) {

if (event.which === 13) {
    $(this).next("input").focus();
} 
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.